# Move constructor and move assignment operator

Tags: c++, move

I'd like to have an exemple of when a move constructor and a move assignment operator need to be necessarily implemented because one cannot rely on the default implementations (that perform a memberwise move).

Comment: Any time you have owning pointers would be one example

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's what `std::unique_ptr<T>` is for.

Comment: Most standard library containers

Comment: When you have a parent pointer in a tree. When you move the Node the parent pointer of the children needs to be changed to point to the destination too.